# Team Foundation Server : branching by release and hotfixes

Tags: tfs, release, branching-and-merging, hotfix

I'm asking myself how manage branching by release and hotfixes.

For example, if we have a main branch, a release branch V1, and a release branch V2 and development branch for each release branch(developmet V1 and V2) and we find a bug in the release branch V1. We have to develop a hotfix, but how merge this hotfix in the release branch V2 and the development branch. Like that : release V1 to Main to release V2 and main to development V1 and V2 ?

If I merge like that, release to release V2 is out of date ?

But how manage the main branch ? Should it not be as stable as possible ? And how this main branch is manage because there is a lot of merge so which version of developpement is in main   ?

With this pattern I will cover cases where customers can have differents versions of a product.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You may want to take a look here; http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/

Comment: I already read this but I don't find answer to my question...

Comment: Can you please post a quick image of you branch hierarchy, and where you are having trouble merging? I'm finding it hard to get my head around the descriptions. Thanks.

Comment: @DaveShaw I've just added a schema. More simply, I would like to work concurrently on different release.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking in "so which version of developpement is in main", would you please clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do that in following order:

1. Create hotfix in `Release 1` branch
2. Merge it to `Main`
3. Merge it to `Release 2`
4. Merge it to whatever `Development` branches you have

(of course, there is a stabilization after each merge)

> But how manage the main branch ? Should it not be as stable as possible ?

Yes, it should. That's why it must be covered with tests.

Comment: So you describe it like my image. But if I have new feature in main, when I merge hotfix in release V2, i bring new my feature ?

Comment: @bobosh No, you don't. You don't have to merge all changes, you can choose the ones you want. That's called "cherrypicking".

Comment: I can choose only one file ?  I hadn't understand that, and informations I found on forum said it was impossible without baseless merge. Thanks for your help. It helps my a lot.

Comment: @bobosh You can choose one (or more) *changeset*.